# Как воспользоваться значением переденным во вторую форму, если обе формы на одной странице, только PHP+HTML+CSS

Tags: php, form

Есть страница регистрации, которая разбита на 2 этапа. В первом этапе пользователь отправляет Ник, далее это значения подставляется во вторую форму, ее так же нужно заполнить пользователю. После отправки второй формы, данные первой формы не передаются на сервер(они остаются во второй форме?). Мне необходимо передать со второй формы все 3 значения my_nik, my_password, my_email есть ли решение данного вопроса, без использования Ajax и JS, только PHP. Я учусь, понимаю что PHP выполняется на стороне сервера, но не могу понять первое значения формы возможно передать на сервер или оно никак не передается? вторая форма передает значения my_password, my_email, ОК, а значения my_nik не передает на другую страницу reg2.php

````
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Зарегистрировать нового пользователя</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button2'])) // вторая форма была введена
{

}
elseif(isset($_POST['button1'])) // вторая форма (ввели первую)
{
    ?>
    <form action="reg2.php" class="wrap" method="post">
        <p class="text">Второй этап регистрации:<br>
        Псевдоним:
        <label>
            <input disabled name="my_nik" value="<?php $my_nik=$_POST['my_nik']; echo $my_nik ?>" />
        </label><br/>
        *Пароль(a-z,0-9):
        <label>
            <input class="border" name="my_password" maxlength="10" />
        </label><br>
        Email:
        <label>
            <input class="border" name="my_email" maxlength="50" />
        </label><br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="ОК" name="button2" /><br>
    </form>
    <?php
}
else // С этого момента начинается именно первая форма
{
?>
<form class="wrap" method="post">
    Желаемый ник:<br>
    <label>
        <input class="border" name="my_nik" maxlength="15" />
    </label><br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Продолжить" name="button1" /><br>
</form>
<?php
} ```

  [1]:https://hostfotos.ru/image/B82
  [2]:https://hostfotos.ru/image/xNx
  [3]:https://hostfotos.ru/image/R4h
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ...
    Псевдоним:
    <label>
        <div><?php echo $_POST['my_nik'] ?></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="my_nik" value="<?php echo $_POST['my_nik'] ?>" />
    </label><br/>
    ...
```

Comment: Благодарю! Отличное решение, такое простое, что мне придётся долго обдумать как я не додумался до этого. Надеюсь другим новичкам это пригодится.

Comment: @Reason Пожалуйста. Успехов!